# get site name from a URL in python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and it seems to have a lot of nice functions that I don't know about. What function can I use to get the root site name? For example, how would I get *faqs.org* if I gave the function the URL "[http://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/kgp_commandline.html](http://ttp://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/kgp_commandline.html)"?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html

Comment: Just to clarify, do you really want just "faqs.org" or do you want "www.faqs.org"? Trying to get the former is a Bad Idea, as it isn't portable to domains like "www.amazon.co.uk".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 >>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
 >>> urlparse('http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html').hostname
 'www.cwi.nl'
```

Answer (score 2):

The much overlooked [urlparse](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.4/lib/module-urlparse.html) module:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = urlparse("http://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/kgp_commandline.html")
print netloc
```

Comment: netloc might includes port number

Answer (score 2):

What version of Python are you learning with?  Note that SilentGhost's answer is for Python 3.0, while Alabaster Codify's will work with the 2.x series.