# Why python reduce() skip over the None element?

Tags: python, reduce

I tried to get the home site of a url. Firstly I used a for loop and achieve the goal.

```
home = ''
my_url = 'http://www.mysite.com/subdir/subdir2/index.html'
for item in my_url.split('/')[:3]:
    home += item + '/'
print  home
```

and I can get

```
'http://www.mysite.com/'
```

Then I come across reduce() which I had never used before. So I get it a shot,here is the code:

```
my_url = 'http://www.mysite.com/subdir/subdir2/index.html'
home = ''
home = reduce(lambda x,y : x + y + '/',my_url.split('/')[:3])
print home
```

this time I got

```
'http:/www.mysite.com/'
```

Is it reduce just ommit the None in it?What's the explanation for the result?

yeah,I know from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508183/get-site-name-from-a-url-in-python) that I could just use urllib's parser function to do it,so I hope here the discussion be focused on the reduce()

Comment: you should use filter() to remove None elements

Comment: @sherpya No,I don't mean to ommit the None element, I'm confused that the reduce() function skip over the None elemnt and leave the result as 'http:/www.mysite.com/' which should be 'http://www.mysite.com/'

Comment: `reduce` doesn't omit anything. There is no `None` element. Where do you think it occurs?

Comment: This is a very bad way to use `reduce()`.   Also, it's a mistake not to use `urllib` for this.  I suggest that we close this question because it's very misleading. The question is very, very confusing.

Comment: I am sorry for not describing the problem clearly.By your rely I know that I unconsciously took ''(empty string) as None. But the reduce() result did cause me a lot of confusion,because I am not familiar with reduce and by reading the document, I still don't quite get how the reduce() functino works. Marcin's explanation is clear and exact,and now I have a better understanding of the process of reduce().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my_url = 'http://www.mysite.com/subdir/subdir2/index.html'
home = ''
home = reduce(lambda x,y : x + y + '/',my_url.split('/')[:3])

my_url.split('/')[:3] #=> ['http:', '', 'www.mysite.com']

'http:' + '' + '/' #=> 'http:/'
'http:/' + 'www.mysite.com' + '/' #=> 'http:/www.mysite.com/'
```

This is not mysterious. Everything works as expected - the problem is that URLs are not uniform, in that the protocol is separated with a double slash.

A useful tool for understanding how reduce works is `scanl` from `functional` ( http://pypi.python.org/pypi/functional ):

```
In [11]: home = scanl(lambda x,y : '%s%s/'%(x,y),my_url.split('/')[0],my_url.split('/')[1:3])

In [12]: home
Out[12]: <generator object _scanl at 0x0000000003DEC828>

In [13]: list(home)
Out[13]: ['http:', 'http:/', 'http:/www.mysite.com/']
```

Note that `str.join` implements a slightly different algorithm:

```
In [16]: '/'.join(my_url.split('/'))
Out[16]: 'http://www.mysite.com/subdir/subdir2/index.html'
```

This is what people usually want - it is equivalent to:

```
In [22]: reduce(lambda x,y : '%s/%s'%(x,y),my_url.split('/'))
Out[22]: 'http://www.mysite.com/subdir/subdir2/index.html'
```

Comment: That's the exact explanation! Thanks~

Comment: Actually, "URLs are not uniform" is not the problem. The approach with `reduce` "works" if we instead do `lambda x, y: x + '/' + y` so that slashes are placed in between the components, instead of after each one except the first. Of course, this way there will be no slash on the end.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You do realise that this information is in my answer already?

Comment: At the end, yes, but the explanation seems a bit awkward to me.

Answer (score 2):

> yeah,I know from this topic that I could just use urllib's parser function to do it,so I hope here the discussion focus on the reduce()

I don't understand why you want to reinvent the wheel if there is a function in the standard library to do so. I really suggest you to not waste your time and get familiar with pythons standard library and *use the functionality provided*.

Anyways, back to your question: When I type: `my_url.split('/')[:3]` I get this:

```
['http:', '', 'www.mysite.com']
```

So there is no `None` in it, just an empty string, which can be used as any other string. And apparently this is what your lambda function for the `reduce` algorithm does, it just concatenates the strings back together. I suggest you use the `strings` `join` method, as it is more readable and easy understandable:

```
>>> parts = my_url.split('/')[:3]
>>> print "/".join(parts)
'http://www.mysite.com'
```

You have to append the last `/` yourself, though.

Comment: thanks Constantinius. I'm just trying to find some occasion that reduce() can be use. Since I know that  are already urllib to achieve this, I won't need to use that 'wheel' snappet now.