# Why python reduce() behaves differently with the `None` element?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I don't understand the answers for a [similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359677/why-python-reduce-skip-over-the-none-element)

It is clear that this should return `True`

```
l = [1,1,1]
reduce(lambda x,y: x== y, l)
```

However, how do you explain this retuns `False` (when `None==None` is `True`)

```
l = [None,None,None]
reduce(lambda x,y: x== y, l)
```

Comment: I guess you misunderstood how reduce works. X and Y are not two different values from the list, but rather an accumulator and a value. It's quite possible for the accumulator (X) not to be in the list. [Reduce docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce) are actually quite confusing in this regard.

Comment: The first example is only "clear" by accident. Replace `1` with `2` instead of `None` and you'll also get `False`.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to check if everything in the list is equal, a simple way is `len(set(l)) == 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
In [214]: l = [None,None,None]

In [215]: reduce(lambda x,y: x== y, l)
Out[215]: False

In [216]: from functional import scanl

In [217]: scanl(lambda x,y: x== y, None, l)
Out[217]: <generator object _scanl at 0x0000000005770D38>

In [218]: list(scanl(lambda x,y: x== y, None, l))
Out[218]: [None, True, False, False]
```

`scanl` shows intermediate results, starting from the initial element. What is happening is that at first initial is returned, then the result of `None == None` (`True`), then `True == None` (`False`), then until the end, `False == None` (`False`).

**Reduce compares the result of the last calculation with the next element in the sequence.**

Comment: Wow, you've had a long ipython session =). Where is that `functional` module from?

Comment: @bereal It's available on pypi; there are a bunch of binary versions, but they are old, so I don't know if they work. I use the pure python version.

Answer (score 8):

Because

```
1 == True # 1 == (1 == 1)
```

is `True`, but

```
None == True # None == (None == None)
```

is `False` (and `None == False` is `False` as well, so once you got `False`, it stays `False`).

That's how `reduce` works: It passes each element and the **result** of the previous evaluation to the callback. And by that it *reduces* a sequence of values to one value.

Comment: +1 because it is perfectly correct, but I'd rather accept @Marcin's answer because it is more detailed

Comment: @rds: That's perfectly fine :) Wikipedia also has an article about these kinds of functions, but it's rather theoretical: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduce_(higher-order_function)

Answer (score 1):

It's not different with `None`, actually, what happens within `reduce` in the first case is

- 1 compared with 1 (== `True`)
- `True` compared with 1 (== `True`)

In the second case, it's

- `None` compared with `None` (== `True`)
- `True` compared with `None` (== `False`)

The funny example would be:

```
>> from operator import eq
>> reduce(eq, [False, False, False])
False
>> reduce(eq, [False, False, False, False])
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second example return `False` because the first time `None == None` gives `True`, but `True == None` gives `False`.

Take a look at the [`reduce` doc](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce) to see how it works.

Also note that "comparisons to singletons like `None` should always be done with `is` or `is not`, **never the equality operators**." - [[PEP8]](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: PEP8 is a style guide. There is no reason why the equality operator cannot be used if it is appropriate.

Comment: @Marcin: What you're saying doesn't make any sense. Yes PEP8 is a style guide, what's the problem? Is `==` more appropriate than `is`? I'm not stating anything wrong nor suggesting bad practices, I'd say that it's quite the opposite.

Comment: Your answer is misleading in that it states as an absolute something which is a mere element of style.