# Parsing site/domain name from URL string

Tags: python, parsing, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get site name from a URL in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508183/get-site-name-from-a-url-in-python)

For URLs like this:

```
http://twitter.com/pypi
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=python
```

I'd like to pull out the `'http://twitter.com'` or `'http://wolframalpha.com'` parts.

The following code works, but I'm looking for suggestions of a cleaner way of doing it...

```
'/'.join(url.split('/',3)[:3])
```

Comment: Seems urlparse has this covered!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508183/get-site-name-from-a-url-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `urllib.parse` (named [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) prior to Python 3) module:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> urlparse("http://twitter.com")
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='twitter.com', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> r = urlparse("http://twitter.com")
>>> r.scheme + '://' + r.netloc
'http://twitter.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another(less readable) method with `urlparse`:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse, urlunparse
>>> urlunparse(urlparse("http://twitter.com/pypi")[:2] + ("",) * 4)
'http://twitter.com'
```